# not able to print instance using def __str__ , in a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I'm learning Python and currently learning Classes.
I'm not able to print the instance of a class, the code is as follows.

```
class CreditCard:
""" This is properly intended, but CNTRL+K resulted in unindentation
     (stackoverflow's cntrl+k)"""


def __init__(self,customer,bank,account,limit):
    """ Initializing the variables inside the class
        Setting the Initial Balance as Zero
        Customer : Name of the Customer
        bank : Name of the Bank
        balance : will be zero, initial
        account : accoount number or identifier, generally a string
        limit : account limit/ credit limit
    """
    self.customer = customer
    self.bank = bank
    self.accnt=account
    self.limit = limit
    self.balance = 0

def get_customer(self):
    """ returns the name of the customer """
    return self.customer

def get_bank(self):
    """ returns the Bank name """
    return self.bank

def get_account(self):
    """ returns the Account Number """
    return self.account

def get_limit(self):
    """ returns the Credit Limit """
    return self.limit

def get_balance(self):
    """ returns the Balance """
    return self.balance

def charge(self,price):
    """ swipe charges on card, if sufficient credit limit
        returns True if  transaction is processed, False if
        declined """
    if price + self.balance > self.limit:
        return False
    else:
        self.balance=price+self.balance
        # abve can be written as
        # self.balance+=price
        return True
    def make_payment(self,amount):
        """ cust pays money to bank, that reduces balance """
        self.balance = amount-self.balance
        # self.balance-=amount

    def __str__(self):
        """ string representation of Values """
        return self.customer,self.bank,self.account,self.limit
```

I'd run that with no error.
I've created an instance,

```
 cc=CreditCard('Hakamoora','Duesche',12345678910,5000)
```

this is what I've been getting.

```
    >>> cc
      <__main__.CreditCard instance at 0x0000000002E427C8>
```

what should I include to make it print the instance, like

```
>>cc=CreditCard('Hakamoora','Duesche',12345678910,5000)
>>cc
>>('Hakamoora','Duesche',12345678910,5000)
```

Kindly use less technical terms(Newbie here)

pastebinlink : https://paste.ee/p/rD91N

also tried these,

```
        def __str__(self):
            """ string representation of Values """
            return "%s,%s,%d,%d"%(self.customer,self.bank,self.account,self.limit)
```

and

```
           def __str__(self):
                """ string representation of Values """
                return "({0},{1},{2},{3})".format(self.customer,self.bank,self.account,self.limit)
```

Thanks,
6er

Comment: Have you tried casting the object to a string? -> `str(cc)`

Comment: Paste your code into the box, then select all the code and press Ctrl-K. For Python, we *really, really need* to see the actual indentation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it returned a string                                                                                                                                                                      '<__main__.CreditCard instance at 0x0000000002EA4048>'

Comment: @user2357112 , https://paste.ee/p/rD91N

Comment: Also, `self.accnt=account` in __init__() should be: `self.account=account`

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing up `__str__` and `__repr__`. Consider the following class:

```
class Test(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return '__str__'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '__repr__'
```

You can see which method is called where:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t
__repr__
>>> print(t)
__str__
>>> [1, 2, t]
[1, 2, __repr__]
>>> str(t)
'__str__'
>>> repr(t)
'__repr__'
```

Also, make sure both of those methods return strings. You're currently returning a tuple, which will cause an error like this to come up:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

Answer (score 2):

Three points:

(1) Ensure that the indentation level of your definition of `__str__` is such that it's a method of the CreditCard class. Currently it seems to be a function defined locally *inside* `charge()` and hence maybe not accessible as an instance method (But it's hard to tell for sure:  `charge()` itself and its fellow methods are also incorrectly indented.)

(2) In `__str__`, return a string, rather than a tuple:

```
def __str__(self):
    """ string representation of Values """
    return str( ( self.customer,self.bank,self.account,self.limit ) )
```

(3) Define an additional `__repr__` method:  this will be used when displaying the object with

```
>>> cc
```

whereas `__str__` will only be used when somebody (like `print`) tries to coerce the object to a `str`.   Here's a minimal example:

```
def __repr__( self ): return str( self )
```

Comment: Thank you, these 2 points worked. the make_payment & __str__ were indented to be local to charge()

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to turn the object into a string (or print it).

Try instead:

```
print(cc)
```

or

```
str(cc)
```

Comment: I've tried str(cc), it resulted in string address,                                                                                                             '<__main__.CreditCard instance at 0x0000000002EA4048>'

Answer (score 0):

Is the file really indented properly? The last two methods (make_payment and __str__) are indented as if they are a part of the 'charge'-method.

I tested this on my system and the indentation on these two methods (especially __str__) caused the same error as yours. Removing the indentation allowed me to print the 'cc' variable the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, str was defined as local to charge(), inside charge(), hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The is the corrected code,
I've learned a grea concept today, learnt about **repr** and **str**.

## Example for class

## Credit card

```
class CreditCard:
""" Just a Normal Credit Card """

def __init__(self,customer,bank,account,limit):
    """ Initializing the variables inside the class
        Setting the Initial Balance as Zero
        Customer : Name of the Customer
        bank : Name of the Bank
        balance : will be zero, initial
        account : accoount number or identifier, generally a string
        limit : account limit/ credit limit
    """
    self.customer = customer
    self.bank = bank
    self.account=account
    self.limit = limit
    self.balance = 0

def get_customer(self):
    """ returns the name of the customer """
    return self.customer

def get_bank(self):
    """ returns the Bank name """
    return self.bank

def get_account(self):
    """ returns the Account Number """
    return self.account

def get_limit(self):
    """ returns the Credit Limit """
    return self.limit

def get_balance(self):
    """ returns the Balance """
    return self.balance

def charge(self,price):
    """ swipe charges on card, if sufficient credit limit
        returns True if  transaction is processed, False if
        declined """
    if price + self.balance > self.limit:
        return False
    else:
        self.balance=price+self.balance
        # abve can be written as
        # self.balance+=price
        return True
def make_payment(self,amount):
    """ cust pays money to bank, that reduces balance """
    self.balance = amount-self.balance
    # self.balance-=amount

def __str__(self):
    """ string representation of Values """
    return str((self.customer,self.bank,self.account,self.limit))
```

Thank you so much